# os.walk doesn't walk

Tags: python

While fiddling around to try to automate some process, I ran into this seemingly very strange behavior of Python's `os.walk()`: when I pass it some directory, it just doesn't do anything. However, when I pass the parent directory, it recurses properly in the path that doesn't seem to work when passed directly.

For example:

```
for root, _, _ in os.walk('F:\music'):
    print(root)
```

produces the following output:

> F:\music
>   [...]
>   F:\music\test
>   F:\music\test\broken
>   F:\music\test\broken\Boards_Of_Canada
>   F:\music\test\broken\Brian_Eno
>   [...]

But when I try with F:\music\test (which was recursed in just fine when `os.walk()` was called on its parent) as such:

```
for root, _, _ in os.walk('F:\music\test'):
    print(root)
```

I don't get any output at all.

Does anybody have an idea what's going on? Am I doing something wrong? Is it some weird limitation of `os.walk()`? I'm really confused.

Comment: Does the same behavior happen when you use `/` (forward slash) as the path separator?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
 for root, _, _ in os.walk('F:\music\test'):
     print(root)
```

...when Python parses the string containing your path, it interprets the `\t` as a Tab character. You can either rewrite your path string literal as `'f:\\music\\test'` or as `r'F:\music\test'` (a raw string, which exists for exactly this reason.)

Comment: This is one reason to hate windows.

Comment: Petty reason to hate Windows. Like saying case sensitive filenames is a reason to hate Linux.

Comment: Case insensitive filenames are another reason to hate Windows.

Answer (score 7):

You should always use forward slashes not back slashes in paths, even on windows. What's happening is that \t is being interpreted as a tab, not slash-tee.

Comment: until you run into `\\?\ ` and forward slashes don't work anymore. and same for batch's `DEL` command, which failed on me while using forward slashes in paths.

Answer (score 2):

you better use os.path.normpath and use any slashes and backslashes (in any amount) you like
it will not only help with your issue but also will make your code cross platform at this point

for root, _, _ in os.walk(os.path.normpath('F:/music/test')):

Answer (score 0):

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("\\"):
    print(root)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)

Windows Path Work with "\\" !